# jQuery Var issue

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, var

Can someone please assist with this. I want to switch the "winWidth" to a div id section: "#about".

The code is

```
function splitColumns() {
        var winWidth = jQuery(window).width() + 15, columnNumb = 1;
        if (winWidth > 1200) {
            columnNumb = 3;
        } else if (winWidth > 992) {
            columnNumb = 2;
        } else if (winWidth > 767) {
            columnNumb = 2;
        } else if (winWidth < 767) {
            columnNumb = 1;
        }
        return columnNumb;
    }

    function setColumns() {
        var winWidth = jQuery(window).width(), columnNumb = splitColumns(), postWidth = Math.floor(winWidth / columnNumb);
        container.find('.portfolio-item').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).css({
                width : postWidth + 'px'
            });
        });
    }
```

The code I came up with which I believe is correct:

```
 var container = $ (‘#about’).width() + 15, columnNumb = 1;
        if (container > 1200) {
            columnNumb = 3;
        } else if (container > 992) {
            columnNumb = 2;
        } else if (container > 767) {
            columnNumb = 2;
        } else if (container < 767) {
            columnNumb = 1;
        }
        return columnNumb;
    }
```

So I think I just need the last few lines of code changed now but I have no idea how to.
FYI; I have no formal training on js so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `jQuery("#about").width()`?

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I believe the above is what I was looking for. Well almost. I just need the last few lines of code now if the above is correct thus far.

Comment: FYI `$('#about').width()` is identical to `jQuery("#about").width()`